# React UI does not make a request to an API on Android device but it does it in Linux

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am writing an app in React in order to make a beautiful UI for my API. When I run it in Arch Linux's Firefox it works well. However, when I run it in my Android device, it seems like the initial API call (inside the `useEffect` of the `App.js`) is not done, not in Firefox neither in Chrome.

I am serving the app in the computer and then opening it with my local IP address (not localhost, obviously) with my phone.

Does anyone know why isn't that working in the phone even though it is working in my Linux machine?

The source code (of the UI and of the API) is in my Github (https://github.com/ToniIvars/Localdrive).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this has something to do with the DNS or cors perhaps, try to debug on your android device what the response from api call is

Answer (score 0):

I suffer a similar problem recently, may relate to unreachable IP address or some security problem.

I recommend using the chrome remote debug tool to make everything clear, in short that's how to do that:

1. First, open your phone debug mode, connect it to the PC with adb debug enable
2. Open chrome on your phone
3. Open chrome on your PC, go to 'chrome://inspect#devices'
4. Wait for a second and you should see your device, click inspect on it
5. Soon you can find out what cause the problem

Here's a full tutorial: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help, I followed this and I solved my error.